# Lag in playing video in android emulator

Tags: android

we have developed a video player using videoview and media controller. When videos running in android emulator(Android 4.4 API level19) it getting lagged and some scenes in videos were also skipped. Kindly give some suggestions regarding this. 
thanks in advance :)

Comment: How is it performing in real device, It may be happening with insufficient memory also right!

Comment: Actually we have added 400mb memory for sd card. Internal storage 200mb, RAM 512 and heap 16.

Comment: [Android Emulator is really slow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/slow-android-emulator?rq=1)

Comment: Run it on a real device. It is probably preforming fine on there. Running the emulator is A LOT of work for your computer, trying to do something taxing on top of that like running a video within it is bound to yield poor performance.

Comment: And also Not able to play some .mp4 videos by showing cant't play this video .... What I can do for it ..

Answer (score 0):

It is not an issue.

As we know android runs on arm processor.

When we run any application on emulator what happens , emulator is a virtual device which is running on desktop processor(e.g intel).

So every statements execute by emulator need to convert from intel understanding format to Arm understanding and result of executed statement to Arm to intel.

Because of this conversion take place for every byte emulator seems slow in terms of performance.

So don't worry it will smooth in real device.